# Combobox in Java repaint

Tags: java, combobox, refresh, repaint

I habe a Java-Problem. 
I made a code which includes a Checkbox (mPortalJCheckbox) and Combobox (mVersandComboBox).

When the Checkbox is true, there should only be 2 items in mVersandComboBox.
Otherwise there should be 3 items.

My Listener is like this:

```
mPortalJCheckbox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
         public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (mPortalJCheckbox.isSelected() == false) {
               System.out.println(mPortalJCheckbox.isSelected());
               mVersandComboBox.removeItemAt(2);             
               mVersandComboBox.revalidate();
               mVersandComboBox.repaint();
            }
         }
      });
```

I think the Combobox removes the last item but it doesn't repaint the Combobox right. Where is my mistake?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need revalidate() or repaint(). The comboBox will repaint itself when data in the combo box model is changed.

The `removeItemAt(...)` method only works if the ComboBoxModel is mutable. Make sure you are using the DefaultComboBoxModel:

```
DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(...);
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox( model );
```

If you need more help then post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.